# Detecting completion of GWT Deck Panel Animation

Tags: html, gwt, animation

I have a Deck Panel with AnimationEnabled(true). I want to know when the animation completes when i change the deck in order to perform other tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer would be there is no way to do it

Answer (score -2):

Did you try subclassing `DeckPanel` and overriding `onComplete()`?

```
public MyDeckPanel extends DeckPanel{
    @Override
    protected void onComplete(){
        super.onComplete();
        //What you want to do once the animation completes
    }
}
```

Comment: onComplete belongs to the private Class DeckPanel.SlideAnimation. Cannot be overridden.